# Package does not exist - error

Tags: jar, package

I am trying to compile a .java file (TransformRTDE.java) that uses several import statements. These statements import .class files present in five external JAR files: dataextract.jar, jna.jar, JRI.jar, JRIEngine.jar and REngine.jar. I have read documentation on how to deal with these import statements while trying to compile your .java file from the command line. However, I do not seem to succeed.

I set up the directory in the command line to be the folder in which my .java file resides. In that same folder, I have put the JAR files. When I try to compile the code using `java -cp dataextract.jar jna.jar JRI.jar JRIEngine.jar REngine.jar TransformRTDE.java`, I get a package does not exist error. I have set up the class path to include the folder in which all my .java and .jar files reside.

I have searched for hours on this without success. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I forgot to mention I also get an error related to annotation processing.
Picture can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/p9ul0olydzmkl6s/error.png

Comment: Please include the complete text of the error message.

Comment: Sorry, I've included the error message from the command line now